# Calculating $\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {{{x\,{\mathop{\ln x\,\rm{d}x}\nolimits} } \over {{{\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}^2}}}} $

Tags: calculus, integration

When i find limit to calculate this, it hard to find. Can anyone finish this ?

$$\int_0^{ + \infty } {{{x\,{\mathop{\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x}\nolimits} } \over {{{\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}^2}}}} $$

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer to the question but a comment on Sami Ben Romdhane's answer, but it is too long for a comment.

Although the integral is $0$ as shown by the hint in Sami's answer, I commented that since the integral from $0$ to $1$ is the negative of the integral from $1$ to $\infty$, it would be interesting to compute the integral from $0$ to $1$. Here is my first attempt which uses
$$
\int_0^1\log(x)x^k\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac1{(k+1)^2}
$$
to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x\log(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\log(x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x^2\\
&=\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{(x+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac14\int_0^1\log(x)\left(1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+\dots\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac14\left(-1+\frac12-\frac13+\frac14-\dots\right)\\
&=-\frac{\log(2)}{4}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Interchange of Summation and Integration**

It has been suggested that I justify the interchange of summation and integration in the penultimate equation above.

Using the formula
$$
\frac1{(1+x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(k+1)x^k+(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)x^n+nx^{n+1}}{(1+x)^2}
$$
we see that on $[0,1]$ the difference between $\frac1{(1+x)^2}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(k+1)x^k$ is less than $(2n+1)x^n$. Therefore, the difference between
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{(1+x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1\log(x)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(k+1)x^k\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
is less than
$$
(2n+1)\int_0^1|\log(x)|x^n\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2}\to0
$$

Comment: (+1)Nice and I suggest that you add a justification of the switching $\int$ and $\sum$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: sorry that took so long, but I was afk for a while.

Comment: Should that formula be obvious?

Comment: @RandomVariable: The formula comes from differentiating
$$
\frac1{1+x}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kx^k-(-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x}
$$
and negating.

Comment: I'm only aware that $\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} x^{k} $ for $|x| <1$.

Comment: @RandomVariable: certainly you are aware of the finite version of the formula for geometric series:
$$
\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}=\sum_{k=0}^nr^k
$$
The formula above sets $r=-x$ and moves the remainder term over.

Comment: Yeah.  It came to me just after I made that comment.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

By the change variable $t=\frac{1}{x}$ prove

$$\int_0^{ + \infty } {{{x{\mathop{\rm \ln x dx}\nolimits} } \over {{{\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}^2}}}} =0$$

Comment: Always good to check that substitution in problems like this (+1). Now the interesting thing would be to compute the integral from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @robjohn Integration by parts: differentiate $\ln x$ should give the integral from 0 to 1:)

Comment: When I tried that, I got a boundary term involving $\log(0)$ and an integral that diverged at $0$.
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x\log(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \left.-\frac12\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+1}\right]_0^1+\frac12\int_0^1\frac1{x(x^2+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: To  overcome this problem just replace $0$ by $\epsilon$ and calculate the second integral $\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}dx$ and then pass to limit $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: Yes, that will fix it (but [it's a bit runny](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJhq9eq_eJg) $\sim$ 2:35).

Answer (score 3):

As the denominator contains $1+x^2,$ let us put $x=\tan\theta $

$$I=\int_0^{\infty } {{{x\ln x\;\mathrm{dx} } \over {{{\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}^2}}}}=\frac12\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sin2\theta \cdot \ln\tan\theta d\theta $$

As $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx,$

$$I=\frac12\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sin2\left(0+\frac\pi2-\theta\right)\cdot \ln\tan\left(0+\frac\pi2-\theta\right) d\theta$$
$$ =-\frac12\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sin2\theta\cdot\ln\tan\theta d\theta=-I$$

As $\sin2\left(0+\frac\pi2-\theta\right)=\sin(\pi-2\theta)=\sin2\theta$ and $\tan\left(0+\frac\pi2-\theta\right)=\cot\theta=(\tan\theta)^{-1}$

Comment: The idea is nice. What I miss is a justification of the finiteness of $I$. Or something else. I see only, but maybe I'm wrong, that you proved only, that if the improper integral exists, then it must be $0$.

Comment: @vesszabo The integral can be proven to exists by splitting at $1$ and bounding it properly. On $[1,\infty)$ it exists by comparison to $x^{-p}$ with some $p>1$. On $[0,1]$ the integrand is bounded and continuous.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Ok. (Of course I also could prove it.) I just added my comment that someone else who read the nice proof don't forget about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the indefinite integral using integration by parts:

$$\begin{align}u&=\ln(x) \\
dv&=\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}du&=\space\space\space\frac{1}{x}dx \\
v&=-\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}\end{align}$$

$$\int {{{x\ln x\;\mathrm{dx} } \over {{{\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}^2}}}}=-\frac{\ln(x)}{2(x^2+1)}+\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{(x^2+1)x}}dx$$

The final integral can be solved using partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)x}=-\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Good thinking.  Get rid of the $\ln x$ term and everything else is rational functions of polynomials, which we know how to do.

Comment: There seems to be a problem at $0$ and $\infty$. $\log(x)$ blows up and the integral diverges.

Comment: @robjohn the limit to infinity ends up being $\infty-\infty$. L'Hopital's can be used to show that it goes to $0$. Same for the right hand limit to $0$.

Comment: @robjohn Hi, in your answer below you (in fact) prove that the integral converges. Here you say that it diverges. Please, correct it.

Comment: @vesszabo: I did not intend to say that the integral in the question diverged. I meant that
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{(x^2+1)x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
diverges. I know that this can be remedied by changing $\int_0^\infty$ to $\int_\epsilon^\infty$ and letting $\epsilon\to0$ and doing the same in the limit term.

Comment: @robjohn I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness here, I should mention that the integral in question is easily amenable to analysis via the residue theorem.  In this case, one would use a keyhole contour about the positive real axis, about which we would consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{z \, \ln^2{z}}{(1+z^2)^2}$$

The contour integral vanishes on the outer and inner  circular arcs of the keyhole  contour, so we are left with the integrals up the real axis at $\arg{z}=0$, and back along the real axis at $\arg{z}=2 \pi$.  Thus, the contour integral is equal to

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x \left [ \ln^2{x}-(\ln{x}+i 2 \pi)^2\right ]}{(1+x^2)^2} = -i 4 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x \, \ln{x}}{(1+x^2)^2} + 4 \pi^2 \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Then again, the contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues of the integrand at its poles inside $C$.  The poles re at $z=i-e^{i \pi/2}$ and $z=-i=e^{i 3 \pi/2}$.  For now, I will simply state that the sum of the residues of $z \ln{z}/(1+z^2)^2$ at these poles is $-i \pi$; therefore, the contour integral is $i 2 \pi (-i \pi) = 2 \pi^2$.  Because this is real, the imaginary part of the integral must be zero; therefore the integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x \, \ln{x}}{(1+x^2)^2} = 0$$

As a bonus, we also see that, equating the real parts of both sides,

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2} = \frac12$$